# Create new table from SELECT with MAX condition using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a book table with few columns and rows like below......

[image: Table name- book]

Later i filter pubdate column between 2000/01/01 and 2000/12/01 by grouping pub_id....with following query

```
select pub_id,max(pubdate) as max_date 
from book 
group by pub_id 
having MAX(pubdate) between '2000/01/01' and '2000/12/01'
```

Results are below :

[image]

Now i want to shift filtered data into new table book1, and i tried following query but it ends in error !!!!

```
select * into book1 
from 
(
    select pub_id,max(pubdate) as max_date 
    from book 
    group by pub_id 
    having MAX(pubdate) between '2000/01/01' and '2000/12/01'
)
```

I tried following thing and it is working

```
insert into existing_table     
(
    select pub_id,max(pubdate) as max_date 
    from book 
    group by pub_id 
    having MAX(pubdate) between '2000/01/01' and '2000/12/01'
)
```

But i want to push filtered data dynamically into new table ?
So please correct my mistake in insert into query ......
Thanks in advance !!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give an alias name

### **Query**

```
select * into book1 
from 
(
    select pub_id,max(pubdate) as max_date 
    from book 
    group by pub_id 
    having MAX(pubdate) between '2000/01/01' and '2000/12/01'
) x
```

Comment: Ya its working and thanks........But what is the concept to use alias name here.... because i learned as alias means - When you create an alias on a table, it is either because you plan to list the same table name more than once in the FROM clause (ie: self join), or you want to shorten the table name to make the SQL statement shorter and easier to read.

Comment: refer: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16516/subqueries-aliases-same-as-main-queries-aliases

Answer (score 1):

Alias can be used to replace a column name or a table name.

In your case, table alias is needed because sql engine deal with set based logic. If you didn't put a table alias for your defined select statement, the sql engine will not know from which set it should be refer to , even your select statement is valid.

Simply put an alias name will let the sql engine to identify which table (act like a unique ID) to refer.

For instance the simple statement, "select * from TableName", the TableName works like a table alias or an Identity to refer to.

(1) It will not work if you just put "Select * from (Select * from TableName)" 

(2) It will work if you put "Select * from (Select * from TableName) x".

Hopefully this explain your doubts.